# React tab navigation is slow

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I created tabs as shown in this example:

http://codepen.io/trey/post/tabbed-navigation-react

It seems to work nicely with little content, but rendering a table slows down switching between tabs, especially on mobile there's a noticeable delay.

Here's the example with a table:

http://jsfiddle.net/xn2bv6v5/

```
var Content = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    ...
```

What's the reason for the slowness?

With my actual more complex data it takes 3-4 seconds to switch tabs on mobile. I also tried changing it so that the tabs switch the visibility of two content components instead of changing what one component renders, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

The only thing that did help was to toggle the content elements visibility with pure js so that no react renders happen, so there must something fundamentally wrong with the react part, I just can't tell what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial render time is not an issue performance-wise you could render all tab content at the same time, and put then in simple wrappers that show/hide them. Then only toggle their visibility. Make sure the visibility toggle lives in a different component than the heavy contents.

Then make sure you implement `shouldComponentUpdate` on the contents and any deeper elements so that React can skip diffing components faster when it knows there are no changes anyway. Splitting your deeper layouts up over several components with well-implemented `shouldComponentUpdate` functions should provide a serious improvement in updates to your view.

The following documentation gives you some more info on `shouldComponentUpdate`, how you should implement it and how it helps improve performance: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html